# set property values from outside an object

Tags: c#

In our project we use a castle container for resolving dependencies. Basically we provide soap services for performing different tasks.

```
  public interface IServiceA
   {
      public ServiceResponse Process(ServiceRequest request);
   }

   public class ServiceA : IServiceA
   {
      public ServiceResponse Process(ServiceRequest request)
     {
         /////process stuff
     }
   }

    public interface IServiceB
   {
      public ServiceResponse ReProcess(ServiceRequest request);
   }

   public class ServiceB : IServiceB
   {
      private IServiceA _svcA;
      public ServiceB ()
      {
        _svcA= Container.Get<IServiceA>(); 
      }

     public ServiceResponse ReProcess(ServiceRequest request)
     {
        ////stuff
        _svcA.Process(new ServiceRequest()); 
     }
   }
```

I can reuse the process method of svcA in order to not have bloated duplicated code, but for this I need to tell svcA when I call its process method , that the call is from within svcB's Reprocess method, so that svcA' process method can look something like

```
public ServiceResponse Process(ServiceRequest request)\
{
   if (calledFromSvcB)
   {
    //do stuff
   }
   //process
}
```

The restriction is I cannot modify the contract meaning the signature of the methods offered by serviceA, or its types.

The only idea i came up with is :

```
 public class ServiceA : IServiceA
       {
         public bool IsCalledFromSvcB {get; set;} 
         public ServiceResponse Process(ServiceRequest request)
         {
             /////process stuff
         }
       }
 public class ServiceB : IServiceB
   {
      private IServiceA _svcA;
      public ServiceB ()
      {
        _svcA= Container.Get<IServiceA>(); 
      }

     public ServiceResponse ReProcess(ServiceRequest request)
     {
        _svcA.GetType().GetProperty("IsCalledFromSvcB ").SetValue(this, true);
        ////stuff
        _svcA.Process(new ServiceRequest()); 
     }
   }
which is really ugly. Any other ideas to inject this?
```

Comment: If `ServiceA` needs to know whether its call is from `ServiceB` or not, then it's not really duplicated code.  If the code overlaps quite a bit between a ServiceB call and a non-ServiceB call, then you should try to reuse as much as possible.  I'd consider refactoring your code, perhaps into a serviceAhelper of some sort.

Comment: the code overlaps 90 % between a call from svcB and a non-svcb call, that's why i have chosen to basically call svcA from within svcB; not sure what you mean with the svc helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a property or field on the inner service won't work if you can have multiple requests being processed at the same time.

A second interface would probably be a better idea. Something like:

```
internal interface IServiceAInternal
{
    ServiceResponse ProcessFromServiceB(ServiceRequest request);
}

public class ServiceA : IServiceA, IServiceAInternal
{
    public ServiceResponse Process(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        return ProcessCore(request, false);
    }

    ServiceResponse IServiceAInternal.ProcessFromServiceB(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        return ProcessCore(request, true);
    }

    private ServiceResponse ProcessCore(ServiceRequest request, bool calledFromServiceB)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private readonly IServiceAInternal _serviceA;

    public ServiceB()
    {
        _serviceA = Container.Get<IServiceAInternal>();
    }

    public ServiceResponse ReProcess(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        return _serviceA.ProcessFromServiceB(request);
    }
}
```